# Prove a assertion concerning Lebesgue space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f_n \in L^1$ such that $f_n\rightrightarrows f$. Then I want to conclude that If $\mu(X)<\infty,$ then $f\in L^1$ and $\int f_n\to\int f$, so I want to make use of the Dominated convergence theorem, the thing is that I don't know which would be my dominating function.

I was trying to figure out if the measure could play that role, but after thinking a little bit I have realize that the measure doesn't have to be bigger than the absolute value of the functions of the sequence.

Another thing I was thinking of, is to apply Fatou's lemma, but I can't ensure that my functions are positive.

So, Can someone help me to prove this theorem please ?

Thanks a lot in advance :).

NOTE: I think this theorem is taken from Folland's Real analysis, modern techniques, and their aplications 2nd Edition :), This is to have all the definitions so we can talk the same language as in the book (this is, same notation and theorems or machinery)

Comment: f_n converges to f in what sense?

Comment: Uniformly to $f$ :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$
\left|\int f_n - \int f\right| \leq \int |f_n - f|
$$
and the quantity on the right can be controlled because of uniform convergence and the fact that $\mu(X) < \infty$.

To prove $f\in L^1$, use something similar such as
$$
\int |f| \leq \int |f - f_N| + \int |f_N|
$$
for some fixed $N \in \mathbb{N}$ large enough.

Comment: How do you control the RHS with the measure ?

Comment: So you don't want to make use of DCT right?

Comment: You can control $|f_n - f|$ uniformly, so once you pull that quantity out of the integral, you are left with the integral of a constant. That is where the measure comes in

Comment: So you mean to write $\int |f_n-f|< \int \epsilon = \epsilon \mu (X)$  right?

Comment: But I have realize that, $L^1$ is almost a Banach space, so I think we want to make use of the norm isn't?, So $f_n \rightrightarrows f$ should mean that $||f_n-f||< \epsilon$ so $\int |f_n -f| <\epsilon $ not $|f_n -f| < \epsilon $ right ?